# Binding doesn't work for properties called Name in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a piece of code that is binding a text box to Object properties like so:

```
txtCreator.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Application, "Creator");
txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Application, "Name");
txtOrganization.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Application, "Organization");
txtGuid.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Application, "UniqueID");
txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Application, "Description");
```

The class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but they all work apart from the one called "Name". No matter what I do that won't bind back from the UI to the object. However, if I change the property name to something else. e.g.

`txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Application, "AnotherName")`

And change the property name, it works first time!!! Is there some special case for a property called Name that means it won't work. I got past it and have it up and running but it's crazy weird.

OK I created a small self-contained example that proves my point. Here's a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            // Will never fire from binding
            _name = value;
            ValueUpdated();
        }
    }

    // This is here because a property called Name doesn't bind correctly. Absolutely INSANE!!!
    public string BindingName
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            ValueUpdated();
        }
    }

    protected void ValueUpdated([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here's the form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal TestClass TestObject { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TestObject = new TestClass();
        this.TestObject.Name = "Hello";

        // Name won't work
        txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.TestObject, "Name");

        // Binding Name will
        //txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.TestObject, "BindingName");
    }
}
```

With the code as is the set will never fire in the Property called Name on the TestClass, however simply uncomment the line that uses the BindingName property and the set fires. As you can see anything but "Name" works and Name doesn't for some reason.

Comment: All controls have a `Name` property, including the form. When you use `Name` as a `dataMember` parameter, it grabs the name of the form. It's not weird at all; generally you should avoid using C# keywords as your variable/property names.

Comment: @Sach: your speculation is unfounded. The source object for the binding is `this.Application`. The data binding in question simply uses that property as the source. The `dataMember` property doesn't arbitrarily select a different object for the source just because the property name is `"Name"` instead of something else.

Comment: _"Is there some special case for a property called Name"_ -- no, there is not. You have done something wrong somewhere else. A trivial example demonstrates that binding a `TextBox.Text` property to an object's `Name` property using `DataBindings.Add()` exactly as you have done works fine. There is something wrong in your code somewhere that's breaking that. You didn't bother to provide an [mcve], so it's not possible to say what it is you did wrong.

Comment: Seems like there is a special case for Name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like I was right, special case for property called Name.

Comment: No idea why you voted this down, I've clearly shown I was right.